# Home page customization of magento

Tags: magento

I am developing an eCommerce website using magento. I have two webstores with a main store. I want to add a popup window on my homepage so that users can choose an option to go to either of the site. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.6.2 and below, (I didn't check in 1.7 but it should be there too) take a look in the folder app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/, you will find the template stores.phtml which does what you need.

You will find also a page.xml layout file into app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml, search the line `<block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>`.

You will have two solutions:

- for me that's not the best solution but you could copy the page.xml and put it into your customized template folder and
  replace in it the line with the language switch with this line
  `<block type="page/switch" name="stores_switch" as="stores_switch"
  template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>`
- or create a new module with its layout file placed into your customized template and set the following lines into
  mymodulelayout.xml layout: `<reference name="header"><block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
  </reference>`

That's a good start to adapt your template with these information. I didn't test it.